# How can I show NULL if There is NULL ELSE Show MAX value

Tags: sql, null, aggregate-functions

I have a table with some attendance data.
And I am trying to work out a table with distinct user with start (MIN) and end (MAX) if no NULL.

Table that I have "time_captured"

| User | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | 60 |
| A | 60 | 120 |
| A | 700 |  |
| C | 120 | 180 |
| C | 540 | 860 |

Result that I desire

| User | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 |  |
| C | 120 | 860 |

Ive tried the below code, however the result is not what I expected (showing back the original table)

```
SELECT
MIN(time_captured.start_time),
CASE 
WHEN
time_captured.end_time IS NULL THEN NULL
ELSE
MAX(time_captured.end_time)
END,
time_captured.user_sign
FROM
time_captured
GROUP BY
time_captured.user_sign,
time_captured.end_time
```

| User | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | 60 |
| A | 60 | 120 |
| A | 700 |  |
| C | 120 | 180 |
| C | 540 | 860 |

Answer (score 5):

If `COUNT(*)` and `COUNT(time_captured.end_time)` are the same, there are no NULL values, i.e. return the `MAX()` value. (Else NULL is returned.)

```
SELECT time_captured.user_sign
       MIN(time_captured.start_time),
       CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = COUNT(time_captured.end_time)
            THEN MAX(time_captured.end_time)
       END
FROM time_captured
GROUP BY time_captured.user_sign
```

Comment: works as desired: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9df49/13

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use conditional aggregation; calculate number of `null` values in `[End]`; if it is equal to `0`, there are no nulls so return max value.

```
select 
  user_sign, 
  min([Start]) c_start,
  case when sum(case when [End] is null then 1 else 0 end) = 0 then max([End])
  end c_end
from time_captured
group by user_sign;
```

Answer (score 0):

I offer my solutions solved in Sql Server 2022 -last 2 and Oracle 21c -first 2 using first_value and last_value:

```
   with x as
       (select p.useru, 
            min(p.startu) over (partition by p.useru) as minim,
            last_value(p.endu) over (partition by p.useru order by (select 1 from dual) nulls last) as maxim2
        from your_table p) 
      select distinct xx.useru, xx.minim, xx.maxim2
        from x xx;
    
        
        with x as
       (select p.useru, 
            min(p.startu) over (partition by p.useru) as minim,
            first_value(p.endu) over (partition by p.useru order by p.endu desc nulls first) as maxim2
        from your_table p) 
      select distinct xx.useru, xx.minim, xx.maxim2
        from x xx;
    


    with x as
           (select p.useru, 
                min(p.startu) over (partition by p.useru) as minim,
                last_value(p.endu) over (partition by p.useru order by case when (select 1 ) is null then 1 else 0 end ) as maxim2
            from your_table p) 
          select distinct xx.useru, xx.minim, xx.maxim2
            from x xx;
        
             with x as
           (select p.useru, 
                min(p.startu) over (partition by p.useru) as minim,
                first_value(p.endu) over (partition by p.useru order by case when p.endu is  null then 0 else 1 end
        , p.endu desc ) as maxim2
            from your_table p) 
          select distinct xx.useru, xx.minim, xx.maxim2
          from x xx;
```

Hope it helps.